# How to further filter Facebook Graph API query on Graph API Explorer for my ad account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get the ad spend and mobile app installs for my app using the Facebook Graph API v2.11 for marketing. In the Graph API Explorer, when I try

```
/act_<my account>/campaigns?fields=insights{actions,spend}&time_range={'since':'2017-07-07','until':'2017-12-12'}
```

In the output, under "insights", I get an object of this type:

```
    "data": [
      {
        "actions": [             
          {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "3"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "like",
            "value": "33"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "1531"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "mobile_app_install",
            "value": "1049"
          }
        ],
        "spend": "8621.03",
        "date_start": "2017-10-28",
        "date_stop": "2017-11-26"
      }
    ]
```

If I want it to fetch only the actions where action type is "mobile_app_install", how can I further filter my query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is possible to filter that on Facebook side just call it like that:

```
/act_<yourAdAccount>/insights
  ?level=campaign
  &fields=actions,spend
  &time_increment=all_days
  &time_range={'since':'2017-07-07','until':'2017-12-12'}
  &filtering=[{field: "action_type",operator:"IN", value: ['mobile_app_install']}]
  &use_account_attribution_setting=true
```

Comment: is there a way to do this on values within nested queries?

Comment: @p0rter sure, use `.filtering([{field: "action_type",operator:"IN", value: ['mobile_app_install']}])`

Comment: Could you please take a look at my most recent question asked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222780/how-does-one-properly-filter-nested-queries-with-fb-graph-api-instagram

Comment: @Vanley Thanks for your answer, worked perfectly - I have an additional question, why have you set `use_account_attribution_setting=true` ?

Comment: @MadhaviMohoni very good question attribution is little bit tricky thing but extremely important for 'Conversion' insights where it's important to specify lookback window to count the occurrences of actions which are called conversions. By default this is set by facebook to ["1d_view","28d_click"] but ad account can have those to set differently, then the numbers which you see in ads manager and api do not match.

Comment: @Vanley Well explained - thanks very much for your help!

Comment: So filtering results only works on the marketing/insights API and not on the rest of the Graph API, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the documentation as well as the adsinsights.py file on github but I cannot find a way to limit the number of action_types returned. You will simply have to do the filtering after you have retrieved the data from the api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/facebookads/adobjects/adsinsights.py

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's how I do it at the moment - unfortunately. At some point if we want to increase the number of KPIs we want to get, we will run into the hourly limit of 200 calls :(