# How does one properly filter nested queries with FB Graph Api (Instagram)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, nested, instagram

I would like to get all media objects that are of type "VIDEO".
Here is my query which always returns all media objects regardless of the type:

```
?fields=media{media_type,insights.metric(reach, impressions)}&filtering=[{field: "media_type", operator: "EQUAL", value: "VIDEO"}]
```

"media.media_type" is also not working.

Thanks in advance!

output format:

```
"data": [
  {
    "media_type": "IMAGE",
    "insights": {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "reach",
          "period": "lifetime",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": 1476
            }
          ],
          "title": "Reichweite",
          "description": "Gesamtanzahl der individuellen Konten, die das Medienobjekt aufgerufen haben",
          "id": "18057498358135767/insights/reach/lifetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "impressions",
          "period": "lifetime",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": 2365
            }
          ],
          "title": "Impressionen",
          "description": "Gesamtanzahl der Aufrufe des Medienobjekts",
          "id": "18057498358135767/insights/impressions/lifetime"
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": "18057498358135767"
  },
```

Comment: Hi @p0rter, did you find any solution/update to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about flattening request? so from this:

```
GET /{ig-user-id}?fields=media
```

should be the same as

```
GET /{ig-user-id}/media?fields=media_type,insights.metric(reach, impressions)&filtering=[{'field':'media_type','operator':'IN','value':['VIDEO']}]
```

and then should be no issue with nested value

Answer (score 0):

try using the operator "IN" instead of "EQUAL", and be sure to have a list in the value. That might work.

Comment: Thank you but this is no answer. "IN" is used - as you said - to go over a list of values. I used and tried this before but changed it to "EQUAL" deliberately.

Comment: I encountered buggy behavior with EQUAL, this is why I resorted to IN