# Could someone tell me how to filter specific action types from facebook's marketing insights api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently using postman to make requests on my companies ad account. The request url is below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_281137323287726/campaigns?access_token=REMOVED&fields=name,insights.time_range({"since":"2020-05-21","until":"2020-05-21"}){campaign_name, account_name, adset_name, ad_name, reach, impressions, frequency, spend, cpm,inline_link_clicks , cost_per_inline_link_click, unique_inline_link_click_ctr, clicks, cost_per_action_type,actions, cost_per_unique_click}
```

this url returns a lot of thing, but the significant bit is here:

```
"actions": [
                            {
                                "action_type": "landing_page_view",
                                "value": "36"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save",
                                "value": "4"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "link_click",
                                "value": "116"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_lead",
                                "value": "5"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "post_reaction",
                                "value": "4"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "video_view",
                                "value": "787"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "post_engagement",
                                "value": "911"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "page_engagement",
                                "value": "911"
                            },
                            {
                                "action_type": "lead",
                                "value": "5"
                            }
                        ],
```

I would like to filter out stuff like "lead", and "landing_page_view"

I have read the api and many other stackoverflow answers: [How to further filter Facebook Graph API query on Graph API Explorer for my ad account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508658/how-to-further-filter-facebook-graph-api-query-on-graph-api-explorer-for-my-ad-a)

So, I have tried to filter myself by doing:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_281137323287726/campaigns?access_token=REMOVED&fields=name,insights.time_range({"since":"2020-05-21","until":"2020-05-21"}){campaign_name, account_name, adset_name, ad_name, reach, impressions, frequency, spend, cpm,inline_link_clicks , cost_per_inline_link_click, unique_inline_link_click_ctr, clicks, cost_per_action_type,actions, cost_per_unique_click}&filtering=[{field:"action_type","operator":"IN","value":["landing_page_view"]}]
```

But i get the following errors:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Filtering field 'action_type' with operation 'in' is not supported",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_data": "An unknown error occurred",
        "fbtrace_id": "Ax3b0DqC6vfKW_4LUmZE-4U"
    }
}
```

Could someone enlighten me why this filtering method does not work? I have tried changing the field to insights.actions etc. and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the that filter work, you can do it like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_281137323287726/campaigns?access_token=REMOVED&fields=name,insights.time_range({"since":"2020-05-21","until":"2020-05-21"}){campaign_name, account_name, adset_name, ad_name, reach, impressions, frequency, spend, cpm,inline_link_clicks , cost_per_inline_link_click, unique_inline_link_click_ctr, clicks, cost_per_action_type,actions, cost_per_unique_click}&filtering=[{field:"action_type","operator":"CONTAIN","value":"landing_page_view"}]
```

The difference is changing the "IN" operator to "CONTAIN", and change the "value" param to a string without the array brackets.