# Facebook Graph API - or

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

Is it possible to give OR filters?
Let's say I do an HTTP GET request, the below will yield an AND filter, where both criteria must be satisfied. Is it possible to change it to OR filter?

```
'filtering':
         "[{'field':'ad.impressions','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':0},   
          {'field':'ad.effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE', 'PAUSED']}]"
```

Couldn't find a single example.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-rule-filters/

Another way to frame the question is basically how to add more filters to e.g. below, with OR criteria.
[How to further filter Facebook Graph API query on Graph API Explorer for my ad account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508658/how-to-further-filter-facebook-graph-api-query-on-graph-api-explorer-for-my-ad-a)

```
/act_<yourAdAccount>/insights
  ?level=campaign
  &fields=actions,spend
  &time_increment=all_days
  &time_range={'since':'2017-07-07','until':'2017-12-12'}
  &filtering=[{field: "action_type",operator:"IN", value: ['mobile_app_install']}]
  &use_account_attribution_setting=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple filters work only as there would be "AND" operator between them. Some desired results can be achieved by "IN" operator or batch requests.