# Graph Explorer - return filtered items with call to 'media'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-reels

I am trying to retrieve a subset of Instagram posts (only media_product_type = 'REELS'), now that these are available from the Graph API.

The accepted answer in this post suggests it's possible but I can't get it to work. Perhaps because it's calling insights rather than media?
[How to further filter Facebook Graph API query on Graph API Explorer for my ad account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508658/how-to-further-filter-facebook-graph-api-query-on-graph-api-explorer-for-my-ad-a)
Appending this, for example, does not work: &filtering=[{field: "media_product_type",operator:"EQUAL", value: 'REELS'}

The working request is:
'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{my account ID}/media?fields=media_product_type,timestamp,id,ig_id,caption,comments_count,like_count,media_url,thumbnail_url,media_type,permalink&limit=200

Is there a way I can return only Reels? Any help much appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: What exactly makes you think these parameters, described somewhere in a documentation provided by MicroSoft, were applicable here to begin with?

Comment: well that's embarrassing! Will edit question, but gist still stands - is it possible to filter response?

Comment: _"is it possible to filter response?"_ - if it was, then https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media should mention it.

Comment: It doesn't, but then it also says media_type for reels is REELS, which it isn't, it's VIDEO.